# How far should I go with "the opposite of Fitts' Law"?

Tags: user-interface

After reading [Jeff's blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html) and being fairly new to GUI programming, I'm wondering what the limits are on applying the "opposite of Fitt's Law." For example, is it a good idea to separate "Yes" and "No" on a dialog screen, or would that conflict with another programming rule? E.g. [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9b6d34c344.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9b6d34c344.png) and [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b3e9223b44.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b3e9223b44.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558197/make-a-run-away-button-in-jquery/2558262#2558262 ;)

Comment: I would suggest that you rename the buttons on the dialogue box to say what they actually do e.g. "Save" and "Exit without saving".

Comment: @Michael "Save" and "Discard". Actually, I prefer Jef Raskin's suggestion of transparent continuous saving, even if exit is through crashing out.

Comment: @Tom only if you also have infinite undo and state markers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe things that are radically unrelated should even be on the same axis. Things which are related but opposing, such as Yes | No dialogs should be separated sufficiently that there is no chance of an accidental mis-click, but more importantly should follow standard conventions. In other words, don't do No | Yes, follow the convention of Yes | No | Cancel, where the rightmost buttons preserve the same state--because many people make an error by finding buttons by position rather than reading the text.

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing, far more errors from putting NO first than from the distance between the two buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think that the idea is to separate them enough to avoid mistakes..
So 300 pixels are too many, but at least 30 is good, 5 pixels are definetely not enough.

You should instead consider what about a cancel button, it should stay separate from YES and NO because it's conceptually different..

Answer (score 1):

Make the buttons say what they user is doing "Save and Exit" and "Exit without saving", and a "Cancel and Return to Application". That removes all the ambiguity for sure, and it doesn't rely on arbitrary placement rules.