# jquery run away submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I see a lot of code for run away buttons (like this one: [Make a run away button in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558197/make-a-run-away-button-in-jquery)

but they only work with the `<button>` tag.

Below is a part of the form code I'm using. I want to have a run away submit button that works with `<input type="submit">`. Is that possible? And how to do this?

```
<div id="FSContact3" style="max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;background-color:none;padding: 5px 0 10px 5px;">
<form action="http://www.example.com/form" id="fscf_form3" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" method="post">

<div id="fscf_div_clear3_0" style="clear:both;">
  <div id="fscf_div_field3_0" style="clear:left; float:left; width:99%; max-width:550px; margin-right:10px;">
    <div style="text-align:left; padding-top:5px;">
      <label style="text-align:left;" for="fscf_name3">Name:<span style="text-align:left;">*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <input style="text-align:left; margin:0;" type="text" id="fscf_name3" name="full_name" value=""  />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="fscf_submit_div3" style="text-align:left; padding-top:2px;">
        <input type="submit" id="fscf_submit3" style="cursor:pointer; margin:0;" value="Submit"  onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Submitting...'; this.form.submit();" /> 
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added the jquery code from the link above into the page's footer with the id #fscf_submit3 or fscf_submit_div3. But that didn't work. I also added the code from http://jsfiddle.net/MTug9/ to my footer and tried with both ids but also no luck.

Comment: Here is a link to my page with the implemented answer from below. http://shoutkey.com/beat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#fscf_submit_div3" ).mouseover(function() {  
  var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*501);
  $( "#fscf_submit3" ).css({'top': numRand, 'left': numRand, 'position':'fixed'});
});
```

You meant something like that probably? You can make it change it position a bit more by changing number next to Math random. 
https://jsfiddle.net/n3z1h647/1/

Comment: It's still not working. Could you have a look at my page? http://shoutkey.com/beat

Comment: check this fiddle then and tell me how it is working on your page compared to that  https://jsfiddle.net/n3z1h647/1/

Comment: When I click on the submit button the button disappears, but I want it to move away from the cursor when the cursor is near to the button.

Comment: and did you check the fiddle? it does move over there https://jsfiddle.net/n3z1h647/1/

Comment: The second version worked. Now the button is moving in jsfiddle

Comment: Could there be something wrong with the jquery I'm using on the page? Have you looked at my page?

Comment: beli:14 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
Yes, you are not using jquery ;)
I mean, you are probably not linking it properly (at least I dont see anywhere it on the website where you link jQuery)

Comment: I believe I'm using jquery /*! jQuery v1.11.3 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */

at the bottom of the page, before your code

Comment: on that page, that you linked - you are not using it. there is nothing in head nor in resources that shows that you are using jQuery. Also $ is not a function is typical when you are not linking jquery properly

Comment: I don't get it. This line is in the page <script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'>. That should including jquery, right?

The error is in the code you gave me above.

Comment: that src doesn't exist for me. Try to link to a proper CDNJS like https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js

Comment: I removed all caching and put the jquery and other scripts in the head. Could you refresh and have a look again. It should be there now.

Comment: sadly it isn't. As I said, the whole problem is with linking jQuery. Add proper CDNJS (or any other source for jQuery), make the error
      'Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function'
disappear and it should be just fine.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right. I added Google's jquery and the button is moving now but I lost my slider... I was using the standard WordPress jquery. Well, that's solved. I'll look for another way to add the slider. 

So, I can confirm your code above is working. Thanks for that.